# Являются ли корутины Котлина решением проблемы с потоками?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, coroutine, kotlinx-coroutines

Решает ли котлин проблему context switching'а потоков и зачем тогда нам нужен **Project Loom**(грин треды)? Я примерно полагаю, что корутины котлина - это все-таки примитив асинхронного программирования, т.е. мы не можем заблокировать поток, иначе будет беда(Не считая *IO Dispatcher*, но там в принципе выделяется отдельный поток, это не совсем релевантно), а **Project Loom** решает проблемы синхронного мира, так как мы можем заблокировать виртуальный поток, а рантайм просто свичнит его. Не уверен насколько у меня правильное понимание, потому что если так смотреть, то **Project Loom** - это не конкурент, а скорее даже способ улучшить корутины, так как будет возможность писать декларативный асинхронный код, не боясь заблокироваться(Как сейчас с *IO Dispatcher*, но лучше). Правильно ли я представляю картину?

Comment: Проблемы переключения контекстов потоков ни то, ни другое, никак не затрагивают. Какие *"проблемы синхронного мира"* имелись ввиду - непонятно. Ни то, ни другое в принципе не требуется для написания асинхронного кода.

Comment: @user7860670 Почему green threads не решают проблемы переключения контекста? Мы же теперь все делаем в юзер-спейс, это быстрее. Под проблемой синхронного мира я имел в виду, что у нас есть какая-то блокирующая операция, мы заблокировали поток, в случае с грин тредами, мы заблокируем только виртуальный поток и все будет нормально, так как они дешевые и проблемы по типу C10k не возникнет. Что значит не требуется, ну да, можно на колбэках все писать, но в котлине идеоматично на корутинах

Comment: А как они ее могут решить? Вызов блокирующей функции в корутине котлина по-прежнему блокирует поток. Project Loom для некоторых сценариев делает возможным трюк, когда рантайм обнаруживает известный блокирующий вызов в контексте виртуального потока, переводит его в неблокирующий и переключает выполнение на другой виртуальный поток. Такие манипуляции возможны только тогда, когда исходный код и так мог быть написан в асинхронной манере. При этом , как и любые решения для общего случая, они будут добавлять оверхед по сравнению с написанием изначально асинхронного кода.

Comment: Асинхронный код не подразумевает обязательного использования корутин, или каких-то других зеленых потоков или прочей поддержики от runtime, колбэков, фьючерсов, промисов, и прочих buzzwords. Другое дело, если вы не хотите думать над организацией асинхронности, тогда да, корутины и looм вполне могут сделать из чего-то более-менее синхронного по виду что-то менее блокирующее.

Comment: @user7860670 я и говорю, что корутины не решают эту проблему, а лум решаем переключая исполнение на другой поток, т.е. нам не нужно беспокоится, что поток может заблокироваться, при этом лум поможет корутинам тем, что, в случае блокировки, сейчас IO диспатчер просто создает отдельный поток, что дорого, а может использовать виртуальный поток. Т.е. с лумом мы по-прежнему пишем thread per request код(в случае сервера), что облегчает работу, но при этом держит такую нагрузку, что и асинхронный вариант сервера(будь то реактор или корутины(как дополнительная абстракция))

Comment: Еще кстати я забыл упомянуть, что корутины и подобные конструкции потенциально могут возобновляться в контексте разных потоков. Я правда не знаю, правильный термин для такой ситуации, однако это дополнительный источник оверхеда. Также не соглашусь на счет того, что один поток на запрос облегчает работу, так как работа в со множеством потоков требует синхронизации.

Comment: @user7860670 у нас stateless сервисы, камон, какая синхронизация.

Comment: Не у нас, а у вас)

Comment: @user7860670 насчет возобновления в разных потоках - это тоже проблема, которую лум сможет решить, например, сейчас, блокирующую транзакцию в базу делать опасно, так как коннекшн хранится в thread local, а если на следующий запуск стейта корутины поток поменяется, а мы должны находится в транзакции, то будет печально, а в лум, наверное, можно это хранить в виртуальном потоке.

Comment: @user7860670 ну если мы пишем сервер, то стейтлесс - это хорошая практика.

Comment: стейтлесс - это когда есть возможность свалить хранение этого самого state на других: либо на клиента который бы передавал релевантный кусок состояния при каждом запросе, либо на базу данных или какой-то другой сервер.